# Enumerate existing text in Vim (make numbered list out of existing text)

Tags: list, vim, enumeration, enumerable

I have a source document with the following text

```
Here is a bunch of text
...
Collect underpants
???
Profit!
...
More text
```

I would like to visually select the middle three lines and insert numbers in front of them:

```
Here is a bunch of text
...
1. Collect underpants
2. ???
3. Profit!
...
More text
```

All the solutions I found either put the numbers [on their own new lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers) or prepended the [actual line of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-to-source-code-in-vim).

How can I prepend a range of numbers to existing lines, starting with 1?

Comment: Reread [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/253041/1890567) from the second question you posted and explain how that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It makes for a good macro.

1. Add the first number to your line, and put your cursor back at the beginning.
2. Start a [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) with `qq` (or `q<any letter>`)
3. Copy the number with `yf<space>` (`y`ank `f`ind  )
4. Move down a line with `j`
5. Paste your yank with `P`
6. Move back to the beginning of the line with `0`
7. Increment the number with <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>
8. Back to the beginning again with `0` (incrementing positions you at the end of the number)
9. End the macro by typing `q` again
10. Play the macro with `@q` (or `@<the letter you picked>`)
11. Replay the macro as many times as you want with `<number>@@` (`@@` replays the last macro)
12. Profit!

To summarize the fun way, this GIF image is `i1. <Esc>0qqyf jP0^a0q10@q`.
[image: Vim list macro]

Comment: Excellent.  That keystroke summary at the end was vital.  Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to first select the lines and then apply these only those (instead of running the macro <number> of times)?

Comment: Do you remember which screen capture software you used to record?

Comment: I've been using LICEcap a while: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: @nocibambi see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337926/vim-macro-on-every-line-of-visual-selection

Answer (score 4):

To apply enumeration for all lines:

```
:let i=1 | g/^/s//\=i.'. '/ | let i=i+1
```

To enumerate only selected lines:

```
:let i=1 | '<,'>g/^/s//\=i.'. '/ | let i=i+1
```

Comment: Could you explain what the top commands is doing?   I get that `i` is  a counter and `g` is matching beginning of lines, but not anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Set non recursive mapping with following command and type `,enum` in command mode when cursor is inside the lines you are going to enumerate.

```
    :nn ,enum {j<C-v>}kI0. <Esc>vipg<C-a>
```

### TL;DR

You can type [`:help CTRL-A`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#CTRL-A) to see an answer on your question.

```
{Visual}g CTRL-A        Add [count] to the number or alphabetic character in
                        the highlighted text. If several lines are
                        highlighted, each one will be incremented by an
                        additional [count] (so effectively creating a
                        [count] incrementing sequence).
                        For Example, if you have this list of numbers:
                                1. 
                                1. 
                                1. 
                                1. 
                        Move to the second "1." and Visually select three
                        lines, pressing g CTRL-A results in:
                                1. 
                                2. 
                                3. 
                                4.
```

If you have a paragraph ([`:help paragraph`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#paragraph)) you can select it (look at [`:help object-select`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#object-select)). Suppose each new line in the paragraph needs to be enumerated.

- `{` jump to the beginning of current paragraph
- `j` skip blank line, move one line down
- `<C-v>` emulates Ctrl-v, turns on Visual mode
- `}` jump to the end of current paragraph
- `k` skip blank line, move one line up

required region selected, we can make multi row edit:

- `I` go into Insert mode and place cursor in the beginning of each line
- `0.`  is added in the beginning of each line
- `<Esc>` to change mode back to Normal

You should get list prepended with zeros. If you already have such, you can omit this part.

- `vip` select inner paragraph (list prepended with "0. ")
- `g<C-a>` does the magic

I have found it easier to enumerate with zeroes instead of omitting first line of the list to enumerate as said in documentation.

*Note:* personally I have no mappings. It is easier to remember what `g <C-a>` does and use it directly. Answer above describes usage of pure `<C-a>` which requires you to manually count whatever, on the other hand `g <C-a>` can increment numbers with given value (aka step) and have it's "internal counter".

Comment: You put "`g<C->` does the magic" when I think you meant `<g<C-a>`.  Also, this is awesome.  Could you help me understand the difference between `g <C-a>` and `<C-a>`?  The latter just increments numbers.  Also, is there some pattern to using `g`?  I know to join lines I use shift+j but to join without spaces I use `g` then shift+j.  Is it some sort of global shortcut modifier?

Comment: type `:help CTRL-A` in vim you will see help for `{Visual}g CTRL-A`. I doubt that `g` modifier has common meaning for each command. I suppose `g` is used as A in alphabet - first and most handy character. Also it is just IMHO, I haven't read all user manual\reference docs yet.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map for @DmitrySandalov solution:

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>n :<C-U>let i=1 \| '<,'>g/^/s//\=i.'. '/ \| let i=i+1 \| nohl<CR>
```

Comment: This is cool, thanks.  I'm not too sharp with  maps, could you add instructions and an example of how to use it in vim?

Comment: See vim help for maps (:help map)

Comment: Ok. If anyone else understands vim maps and this answer and can augment it with an example of how to use it and input/output, that would be appreciated.